# browser is not reflecting changes, wordpress installed. Can you please help

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, cloud-hosting

I have strange problem.
For a project we are using following cloud hosting.

http://www.rackspace.com

I have installed wordpress on four sub-domains on this server.

Now i am facing a strange problem.
Sometimes when i make changes in theme flies, browser does not reflect those changes.

Like in abc.php file i have included xyz.php file.
I made some changes to xyz.php but when i open that page in browser, i can not see changes.
The issue is more worst, because even i tried to delete/rename xyz.php but i can still see previous include on abc.php page.

It was happening before, but after some time behaviour was normal.
Now its been 2 weeks and i am facing this problem.
I have contact hosting supprt, but they do not accept any issue. They say there is some issue in your wordpress. 
I am sure that i do not have any cache plugin in wordpress.
Can you help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried different browser by clearing browser's cache ?

Comment: @Bishwo: yes i have tried almost all major browsers like Chrome, firefox, IE, Safari, Opera ....

Comment: Why -1 to my question? :-@ if you cant help then please do not destroy my repo. I am in trouble main1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually CMS implement some cache mechanism. I guess your problem comes from that.
Check if you have some "flush cache" option in the admin panels.

Comment: Well, If it is the problem. then it should happen with all files. Isnt it strange that this is for some files and transfers from one file t, seems like virus :-|

Comment: And I have just checked, wordpress just have query cahce, No out put or page buffering.